# Stormpath secure rest api

Tags: okta, stormpath, okta-api, express-stormpath

I followed the example here https://stormpath.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-mobile-api-security

and here to acquire an access token

https://support.stormpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/225610107-How-to-Use-Stormpath-for-Token-Management

> ```
> "use strict";
>
> import { ApiKey } from 'stormpath'; 
> import { Client } from 'stormpath';
>
> let apiKey = new ApiKey(process.env.STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID,
>      process.env.STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET);
>
> let spClient = new Client({apiKey: apiKey });
>
> spClient.getApplication(process.env.STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF,
>    function(err, app) {
>
>     var authenticator = new OAuthAuthenticator(app);
>
>     authenticator.authenticate({
>         body: {
>             grant_type: 'password',
>             username: username,
>             password : password
>         }
>     }, function (err, result) { 
>         if (!err) console.log(err);
>         res.json(result.accessTokenResponse);
>     });
> });
> ```

I was able to acquire a access_token. I use this token to hit my api with Header Authorization Bearer {access_token}

However, when i put in the middleware `stormpath.apiAuthenticationRequired`, i keep getting this warning and my api is returned with 401

```
(node:57157) DeprecationWarning: JwtAuthenticator is deprecated, please use StormpathAccessTokenAuthenticator instead.
```

Comment: Hey @timpham, do you have an existing Stormpath account on https://api.stormpath.com? If not, you won't be able to follow these tutorials, as registration has been disabled on Stormpath's site. You can read more about that here: https://stormpath.com/blog/stormpaths-new-path

Comment: Yes i do. And here's the doc https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/product-guide/latest/auth_n.html#how-token-based-authentication-works which I follow. It still show sample code using the old JwtAuthenticator instead.